# How do I Enable Debugging Mode in Xperia M Without Booting in?

Tags: flash, debugging, adb, sony-xperia, fastboot

I'm unable to access my device, because it asks me to type in a password to decrypt the internal storage. I did not, in fact, place any password here, so I don't know how I got here. I've been trying to flash the device with another firmware for this reason — including CyanogenMod — but it wouldn't let me because apparently I'm not in debug mode. I can't enable debug since I can't seem to be able to boot up normally.

How do I enable debug mode without having to boot my phone, perhaps via Fastboot or Flashtool?

Answer (score 0):

If you enter wrong password in the decrypt dialog 30 times, the device will 
factory reset itself and you can start all over again. In Android L, because of Factory Reset protection, you need however to log on the same Google account again after factory reset.

Hope this helps.

/Marek Pola, Sony Mobile.

Comment: Nope, didn't help, unfortunately. Don't know why. :(

Comment: What is your SW version? If decrypt dialog doesn't work, try to re-flash the device using PC Companion while clearing the data. Then you should be able to start up the device, but Factory Reset Protection will still be active, during setup wizard you must enter your Google account credentials. /Marek Pola, Sony Mobile.